# Specifying path and filename dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a export pop-up window, where the user will be prompted to specify path and filename (a "save as" more or less) whereas the file will be written to the specified path with the desired name. I have the export method written, but i cant for the life of me find out how to create the "save as" dialog.

Comment: You need to learn about HTTP and the difference between the server and the client.

Comment: You have to expose the file as a separate link.  The browser will take care of the rest.  Are you trying to let the user download a file which can be accessed via a simple URL?

Comment: In particular, you need to send it as a response.